# How can I improve the code for contour plot of the real part of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$?

Tags: plotting

I try to plot level curves of the real part of the complex function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ with

```
ContourPlot[Re[1/(x + I y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Exclusions -> {x^2 + y^2 == 0}]
```

But I get

[image]

It is acceptable though, there is a problem at the origin $(0,0)$. How can I improve the code?

Comment: Try increasing the `MaxRecursion` option in `ContourPlot`. `MaxRecursion -> 4` gives a pretty good result

Comment: You can try `PlotPoints->100` option too

Comment: @Marchi: thanks for your comment. That solves the problem. Would you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve the rendering issue by increasing the `MaxRecursion` option in `ContourPlot`.

```
ContourPlot[Re[1/(x + I y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Exclusions -> {x^2 + y^2 == 0}]
```

[image]

From @BlacKow's comment, the same result can be achieved by increasing the number of `PlotPoints`:

```
ContourPlot[Re[1/(x + I y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Exclusions -> {x^2 + y^2 == 0}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ContourPlot[Re[1/(x + I y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, Exclusions -> {x^2 + y^2 == 0}, 
MaxRecursion -> 6, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
ClippingStyle -> Automatic, Frame -> False, 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
PlotPoints -> 150, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: This one is very nice! Thank you for your answer!